# Woocommerce order is not saved in database until I load another page in the store

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This ia very strange problem with Wordpress 6.1.1 and Woocommerce.

When an order is placed I need to do something with that order just after it is created in database, however, I realized about the following.

When an order is placed and the Woocommerce success page is shown, I receive the mail with the message "Your order 1630 was placed".

While I still stay in the success page, and I see the database, table `wc_order_product_lookup` does not show the new order whose `order_id` is 1630. I looked for it in all other order related tables, such as `wc_order_stats` and others, and none contains the newly created order.

However, when I move to other page in the store, and see the database again, I check that the order 1630 was finally saved in all related tables. By using database terminology, the order row is commited to the database when other store page is browsed.

It seems some sort of cache is affecting. Is there a way to do a COMMIT to the database so the order could be seen in the orders tables when the success page is shown? I can do that in a plugin, but I need to know if there is a call to `$wpdb` object to do that.

Thanks

Comment: ... experiencing the same behaviour with WP 6.2.2 and WooCommerce 7.9.0

Comment: It seems after about 60 secs the order data gets stored into the table `wc_order_product_lookup` without loading any other page